# How to clear TextView on any event?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textview

I am making an app that shows a result in a TextView and I would like to clear this TextView whenever a spinner, button, segmented control (excluding my calculate button) is pressed. Is there anyway to implement this without having to put TextView clearing code in every Click event in the layout?

Comment: use textview.setText(""); on click of all events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
if(v!= calculateButton)
{
textView.setText("");
}
}
```

All onClick events you can handle like this but for spinner event or any other layout event you have to do this

```
 textView.setText("");
```

Hope this help ..

Comment: I just didn't wanted to make a setText call in everything, this will work for buttons thank you

Answer (score 1):

just use :

```
TextView textView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // MAKE YOUR TEXT EMPTY
            textView.setText(""); // NOW TEXT WILL BE EMPTY
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it works for you. its simple...
on your button click just set textview text empty using **txt.setText("");**